# Subreport not working as expected on Matrix with drill downs

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, subreport

I need to create subreport link on main report(not the drill down but the first page).

Design below:
 [image: Design_Main Report]

But, I see sub-report only after drill-down to first level on Column (NULL) see below:

[image: Subreport after drill down on Column]

Let me know if I can see sub-report  before drill-down as I am using Matrix with drill downs both on Row and Column.

Thanks,
AR

Answer (score 1):

To see the sub-report link before drilling down you would need to add a cell that's outside of those groups. If you right-click on a cell you can insert a row/column outside of the group above it. You can have sub-headers above each grouping level depending on how you want to design it.

Comment: Steven - It allows me to see subreport only after drill down on Column and adds an extra blank space on the report

Comment: Have you tried putting the subreport in the blank space?